# Create environment having access to libraries but not to .GlobalEnv

Tags: r

I would like to evaluate some code in the environment which will have
the access to libraries (all environments above `.GlobalEnv`) but won't have
access to the objects created in the `.GlobalEnv`.
I've tried couple solutions but none seemed to work as expected

#### 1. new environment in .GlobalEnv

Here environment created in the `.GlobalEnv` have an access to the other
objects in the `.GlobalEnv`.

```r
.GlobalEnv$ee <- environment()
eval( 
  parse(text = "library(dplyr);mutate(iris, x = 1)"), 
  envir = .GlobalEnv$ee
)
var_in_global <- "x"
eval(
  expr = parse(text = "ls()"), 
  envir = .GlobalEnv$ee
) # expect empty
eval(
  expr = parse(text = "print(var_in_global)"), 
  envir = ee
) # expect error
```

#### 2. New environment as a child of .GlobalEnv

This one is Coded different way but result is th same as 1st

```r
ee <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
eval(
  parse(text = "library(dplyr);mutate(iris, x = 1)"), 
  envir = ee
)
var_in_global <- "x"
eval(
  expr = parse(text = "ls()"), 
  envir = ee
)
eval(
  expr = parse(text = "print(var_in_global)"), 
  envir = ee
)
```

#### 3. New environment as parent of global

In this case environment doesn't have an access to the `.GlobalEnv` objects
but libraries loaded after will be attached below, so the environment doesn't
have an access to these libraries as well.

```r
ee <- new.env(parent = parent.env(globalenv()))
eval(
  parse(text = "library(dplyr);mutate(iris, x = 1)"), 
  envir = ee
)
var_in_global <- "x"
eval(
  expr = parse(text = "ls()"), 
  envir = ee
)
eval(
  expr = parse(text = "print(var_in_global)"), 
  envir = ee
)
```

#### 4. Using library(..., pos = 3)

Using answer from @Allan Cameron, I've tried to make this code working. And `library(dplyr);mutate(...)` were correctly evaluated in new environment.

```r
ee <- new.env(parent = parent.env(globalenv()))
eval(
  parse(text = "library <- function(...) base::library(..., pos = 3)"),
  envir = ee
)
eval(
  parse(text = "library(dplyr);mutate(iris, x = 1)"), 
  envir = ee
)
var_in_global <- "x"
eval(
  expr = parse(text = "ls()"), 
  envir = ee
)
eval(
  expr = parse(text = "print(var_in_global)"), 
  envir = ee
)
```

However, problem is much deeper. Some packages have more dependencies which are loaded along. Consider this example where I've replaced `library(dplyr);mutate()` with `library(Hmisc);impute(...)`. This example fails - couldn't find `impute` function (which is wrong)

```r
ee <- new.env(parent = parent.env(globalenv()))
eval(
  parse(text = "library <- function(...) base::library(..., pos = 3)"),
  envir = ee
)
eval(
  parse(text = "library(Hmisc);impute(iris[,1], 1)"), 
  envir = ee
) # expect to work
```

Do you have any ideas how to make an environment which will be
"parallel" node to the global, and still have libraries attached before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `library`, by default it attaches the package at `pos = 2` in the search path:

> **pos**
> the position on the search list at which to attach the loaded namespace. Can also be the name of a position on the current search list as given by search().

So, when I start an R session and do `search()`, I get:

```r
#>  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"    
#>  [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
#>  [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
#> [10] "package:base"
```

And when I call `library(dplyr)` then repeat `search()`, I get:

```r
#>  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:dplyr"     "tools:rstudio"    
#>  [4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
#>  [7] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
#> [10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

So, if you make `ee` have the same parent as the Global environment before attaching any packages, you will have the problem that the packages are placed *between* the Global Environment and `ee`'s entry into the search path.

There are a few ways round this, but perhaps the simplest is to start a new R session and define:

```r
library <- function(...) base::library(..., pos = 3)
```

Which ensures that packages loaded in the Global Workspace are always placed after `ee`'s "entry point" to the search path. This produces the desired behaviour:

```r
ee <- new.env(parent = parent.env(globalenv()))

var_in_global <- "x"

eval(expr = parse(text = "ls()"), envir = ee)
#> character(0)

eval(expr = parse(text = "print(var_in_global)"), envir = ee)
#> Error in print(var_in_global): object 'var_in_global' not found

library(dplyr) # Note this is called in the global environment

eval(parse(text = "head(mutate(iris, n = 1), 5)"), envir = ee)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species n
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 1
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 1
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 1
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 1
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 1
```

Note that as a (possibly desirable) side effect, since the modified `library` function is defined in the global environment, then if `library` is called from inside `ee`, it will be `base::library` that is dispatched, and any packages loaded within `ee` will therefore only be accessible to `ee`.

**EDIT**

If you want code called within `ee` to affect the global search path as well as `ee`'s search path, you could try:

```r
ee <- new.env(parent = parent.env(globalenv()))

ee$library <- function(...) {
  mc <- match.call()
  mc[[1]] <- quote(base::library)
  eval(mc, envir = globalenv())
  this_env <- parent.frame()
  if(!identical(this_env, globalenv())) 
  parent.env(this_env) <- parent.env(globalenv())
}
```

This gives us:

```
eval(
  parse(text = "library(Hmisc);impute(iris[,1], 1)"), 
  envir = ee
)  

#>  [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4 4.6 5.0 4.4 4.9 5.4 4.8 4.8 4.3 5.8 5.7 5.4 5.1 5.7
#>  [20] 5.1 5.4 5.1 4.6 5.1 4.8 5.0 5.0 5.2 5.2 4.7 4.8 5.4 5.2 5.5 4.9 5.0 5.5 4.9
#>  [39] 4.4 5.1 5.0 4.5 4.4 5.0 5.1 4.8 5.1 4.6 5.3 5.0 7.0 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 5.7 6.3
#>  [58] 4.9 6.6 5.2 5.0 5.9 6.0 6.1 5.6 6.7 5.6 5.8 6.2 5.6 5.9 6.1 6.3 6.1 6.4 6.6
#>  [77] 6.8 6.7 6.0 5.7 5.5 5.5 5.8 6.0 5.4 6.0 6.7 6.3 5.6 5.5 5.5 6.1 5.8 5.0 5.6
#>  [96] 5.7 5.7 6.2 5.1 5.7 6.3 5.8 7.1 6.3 6.5 7.6 4.9 7.3 6.7 7.2 6.5 6.4 6.8 5.7
#> [115] 5.8 6.4 6.5 7.7 7.7 6.0 6.9 5.6 7.7 6.3 6.7 7.2 6.2 6.1 6.4 7.2 7.4 7.9 6.4
#> [134] 6.3 6.1 7.7 6.3 6.4 6.0 6.9 6.7 6.9 5.8 6.8 6.7 6.7 6.3 6.5 6.2 5.9
```

However, we need to be careful. If `library` is called in the global environment, this will not update the search path for `ee`. So we would need to have a global function like:

```r
library <- function(...) {
  base::library(...)
  parent.env(ee) <- parent.env(globalenv())
}
```

Of course, it would be much nicer to have your own package do this. That way, you can have a single `library` function which tests its calling frame and dispatches the appropriate method, without having these spare `library` functions floating around the workspaces.

<sup>Created on 2020-09-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I will add only one minor thing. eval(quote(library <- function (...) base::library(..., pos = 3)), ee)

Comment: Another thing to remember is that library could not be overwritten in baseenv

Comment: I need `library(...)` to be evaluated in the `ee` environment. Also if you change your code to load `library(Hmisc)` and evaluate `eval(parse(text = "impute(iris[,1], 1)"), envir = ee)` - this would fail also.

Comment: @GoGonzo do you mean if you call `library` from `ee` it should make the package available in both the global environment and `ee`?

Comment: @Allan Cameron Yes, I need to enable `library` call in `ee`. Issue I have is specific. User can specify custom call which is evaluated in separate environment (`ee`). User can specify any code and it needs to be executable.

Comment: This line is a masterpiece `parent.env(this_env) <- parent.env(globalenv())`. In my opinion this solution with high probability is a correct one. However as always should be properly tested.

Comment: @AllanCameron smart one! Thanks